# Add sound on Android Studio Application

Tags: android, audio, effects

How do I add a sound effect to a game when the mission is over? I am currently using Android Studio also.

Answer (score 4):

First create a folder named sounds or whatever you want in res folder. Than put your sound file in the folder that you created. Add this code to your app.

```
    MediaPlayer song = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.sound_folder.sound_name);
    song.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to first get hold of the sound that you need to play when the mission is over. example. Using a .wav file. Next place the .wav file in the raw folder in the res folder. You can find the sound you need free on sites which provide the same. Next in your code where you need to play the sound.

```
  private SoundPool sounds;
  private int sExplosion;
  //declare variables
  sounds = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
  sExplosion = sounds.load(context, R.raw.explode, 1);
  sounds.play(sExplosion, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);
```

here explode.wav is the sound that i need to play

Comment: Where is the raw folder in the res folder? I'm sorry but I am new to this and don't understand coding.

Comment: For some reason, the code is coming up with mostly 'cannot resolve symbol' and 'missing method/ body'. How do I fix this?